# taking the value of the cell from SAP report

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I have the report in SAP, I need to take the value from the cell (order number).

How can I get this?

I wanted to use something like
`session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").currentCellRow = 12`

but this refers only to row number (12).

How I can take the value of the cell from e.g. row 12 and column 9?

Thanks

Comment: I guess your "report" implements a `GuiGridView` object. I don't see the relationship between getting the value of a cell and setting the property `currentCellRow`. Setting the column would not help you in getting the value of one cell. Could you clarify your question? (NB: `currentCellColumn` contains the column **name**, column numbers are not used in SAP GUI Scripting)

Comment: My point here is - I need to save the invoice under the name of the order. Order numbers are listed in the report (as the following positions of the list, not as the header).

Comment: Please have a look at the similar issue at the link below: https://answers.sap.com/questions/698148/sap-grid-copy-to-excel.html

Comment: And how I can copy the whole line from the SAP report?

Comment: I have something like this

Comment: ```For i = 0 To rows_sap
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").currentCellColumn = "REFBN"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectedRows = i
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").Copy```

Comment: however I have the error on the last line of the code - with .copy

Answer (score -1):

I have found it Easier to refer directly to the cell you want info from.

```
MyGrid = "wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell"
iRows = session.findById(MyGrid).RowCount()

Do While i < iRows ' i default value of 0
 session.findById(MyGrid).firstVisibleRow = i 'This is an auto scroll to keep info loading with more then 100 rows
 SAP_Info = session.findByID(MyGrid).getcellValue(i,"REFBN") 'SAP_Info as a variable to store the data rather than using copy/paste 
 
 i=i+1
 Cells(i, 1).Value = SAP_Info 'set to excel active work sheet cells in column A
Loop
```

If you wish to pull the whole row I recommend using an Array and set to a table. Here is my report for getting confirmation info of man-power.

```
Sub Con_Report()
Dim ArrCells() As Variant

    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)
    Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)
MyGrid = "wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell"
hRows = session.findById(MyGrid).RowCount()

ReDim ArrCells(1 To hRows, 1 To 9)
session.findById(MyGrid).firstVisibleRow = 0
Do While h < hRows  'Fill excel sheet
    session.findById(MyGrid).firstVisibleRow = h
    ArrCells(h + 1, 1) = session.findById(MyGrid).getcellValue(h, "INGPR")
    ArrCells(h + 1, 2) = session.findById(MyGrid).getcellValue(h, "AUART")
    ArrCells(h + 1, 3) = session.findById(MyGrid).getcellValue(h, "AUFNR")
    ArrCells(h + 1, 4) = session.findById(MyGrid).getcellValue(h, "ZORDDESC")
    ArrCells(h + 1, 5) = session.findById(MyGrid).getcellValue(h, "TPLNR")
    ArrCells(h + 1, 6) = session.findById(MyGrid).getcellValue(h, "IARBPL")
    ArrCells(h + 1, 7) = session.findById(MyGrid).getcellValue(h, "NAME")
    ArrCells(h + 1, 8) = session.findById(MyGrid).getcellValue(h, "ISDD")
    ArrCells(h + 1, 9) = session.findById(MyGrid).getcellValue(h, "ISMNW")
    
    
    h = h + 1
Loop
Range("B3").Resize(UBound(ArrCells, 1), UBound(ArrCells, 2)).Value = ArrCells
End Sub
```